# How to compute the transfer maps for G-theory of Noetherian schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-k-theory, blow-ups

Let $k$ be a field and $R$ be the ring $k[x,xy,xy^2,xy^3]$. Let $X$ be $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ and $\tilde{X}$ be the blow-up of $X$ along the maximal ideal $I$ of $R$ generated by $x,xy,xy^2,xy^3$.I have proved that $\tilde{X}$ is line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, so that the $G$-theory groups of $\tilde{X}$ agree with the $G$-theory groups of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.
I am trying to compute the $G$-theory groups of $X$ by using the long exact sequence induced by the blow-up square associated to $X$ and $I$, which is $\cdots\rightarrow G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_n(k)\oplus G_n(\tilde{X})\rightarrow G_n(X)\rightarrow G_{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow\cdots$.
So far, I only managed to show that the map $G_0(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_0(k)$ sends the class of the structure sheaf of $\mathbb{P}^1$ to the class of $k$ and sends the class of the twisted sheaf $O(-1)$ to 0.Note that $G_0(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is the free abelian group based on the classes of $O$ and $O(-1)$.So I know the map $G_0(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_0(k)$.
But I don’t know how to compute the maps $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_n(k)$ for all $n\geq 1$ and the maps $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_n(\tilde{X})$ for all $n\geq 0$.
Could someone help me with this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I guess the maps $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1) \to G_n(\tilde{X})$ are all isomorphisms, hence $G_n(X) = G_n(k)$.

Comment: Since $G_*(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is freely generated by $O$ and $O(-1)$ as a graded $G_*(k)$-module, we know the map $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\to G_n(k)$ for all $n$ as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Could I ask why the maps $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_n(\tilde{X})$ are all isomorphisms?

Comment: Because, as you said, G-theory of $\tilde{X}$ agrees with the G-theory of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: I would like to clarify the claim that the $G$-theory of $\tilde{X}$ agrees with the $G$-theory of $\mathbb{P}^1$. This comes from the homotopy invariance of $G$-theory for Noetherian schemes, which says that if $p:E\rightarrow X$ is a geometric vector bundle over a Noetherian scheme X, then the base change $p^*:G(X)\rightarrow G(E)$ induces isomorphisms on the $G$-theory groups. But the problem now is the map I am trying to compute is the $G$-theory transfer map, which is covariant with respect to the underlying morphism of schemes. Could you help me with this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: The $G$-theory transfer map is induced by a proper morphism of Noetherian schemes, and is covariant with respect to the underlying proper morphism. In this case, the proper morphism is the inclusion of the exceptional divisor into the blow-up $\tilde{X}$.

Comment: What I have tried to compute this $G$-theory transfer map is to examine the commutative ladder diagram formed by the Mayer-Vietoris sequences induced by the homotopy Cartesian square of the standard affine cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and that of the corresponding open cover of the blow-up $\tilde{X}$. But I am stuck for this method.

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski: Could you please explain how to compute the map $G_n(\mathbb{P}^1)\rightarrow G_n(k)$ for all $n$ based on “$G_*(\mathbb{P}^1)$ is freely generated by $O$ and $O(-1)$ as a graded $G_*(k)$-module”? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If $\tilde{X}$ is the total space of a line bundle $L$ and $i \colon \mathbb{P}^1 \to \tilde{X}$ is the embedding of the zero section there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to p^* L^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}} \to i_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to 0.\tag{*}
$$
If you tensor it with $p^*F$ and observe that
$$
p^*F \otimes i_* \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \cong 
i_*i^*p^*F \cong i_*F
$$
(by projection formula) you get an exact sequence
$$
0 \to p^*(F \otimes L^\vee) \to p^* F \to i_* F \to 0.
$$
This gives you an expression for the map $i_*$ in terms of the map $p^*$.

EDIT. Let me explain the sequence $(*)$. The variety $\tilde{X}$ is smooth and $Z = i(\mathbb{P}^1) \subset \tilde{X}$ is a Cartier divisor. Therefore, the ideal $I_Z$ is a line bundle.

On the other hand, every line bundle on $\tilde{X}$ is the pullback of a line bundle via $p$. So, to identify $I_Z$ it is enough to understand its restriction to $Z$. We have
$$
I_Z\vert_Z = \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-Z)\vert_Z = \mathcal{O}_Z(-Z) = \mathcal{O}_Z(3),
$$
because the normal bundle of $Z$ is $\mathcal{O}(-3)$. Thus
$$
I_Z \cong p^*\mathcal{O}(3),
$$
and the sequence $(*)$ is just the Koszul resolution of $\mathcal{O}_Z$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and explanations.  Could you explain why the inclusion of the exceptional divisor to the blow-up $\tilde{X}$ is the embedding of the zero section of the line bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1$? Thank you very much for your kind and patient help.

Comment: Also, could you explain how you derived the first exact sequence?I understand that it implies the third exact sequence by applying the projection formula. But I don’t know how to derive the first exact sequence. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Boris: See an explanation about the exact sequence in the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind explanations. I will try my best to understand them.

Comment: Could you please help me with the following:why is every line bundle on $\tilde{X}$ the pullback of a line bundle by p?And why is the normal bundle of $Z$ $O(-3)$? Thank you very much for your kind and patient help.